# Handling multiple asynchronous requests in Azure?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-mobile-services

For the reading a table script shown below, I am trying to run the query in the parameter and for each result trying to append a value from a different table to the result. But due to asynchronous nature of azure, request.respond() is always called before getInvites. Which means that the results are never appended with invites.

```
function read(query, user, request) {

    request.execute({
        success: function (results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                getInvites(results[i].id, function (invites) {
                    console.log("Assigning results.invites"); //runs second
                    results[i].invites = invites;
                });
            }
            console.log("Request Responding"); //runs first
            request.respond();
        }
    });

}

function getInvites(id, cb) {
    var InvitesTable = tables.getTable("Invites").where({
        "PlanID": id
    }).select("UserID", "Attending");
    InvitesTable.read({
        success: function (results) {
            if (cb) cb(results);
        }
    });
}
```

This is a followup question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326849/synchronous-request-in-windows-azure) as I am unable to use external libraries in Azure. So how can I workaround the problem?

Comment: Any custom events in this framework? Or can you use jQuery or is there  `.addEventListener()` method for an object you have access from your `getInvites`. just give me one of these options.

Comment: None, sadly. Here is a reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554226.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asynchronous nature of the operations makes that a little challenging. What you need to do is to only call `request.respond()` once all the operations are done. I really miss the `await` keyword which I'm so fond from C#, but I've used an "asynchronous for loop" before, and it's worked quite well. Your code would look something like the one shown below:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    request.execute({
        success: function (results) {
            var index = 0;
            var executeStep = function() {
                if (index === results.length) {
                    // all invites have been retrieved
                    console.log("Request Responding");
                    request.respond();
                } else {
                    getInvites(results[index].id, function(invites) {
                        console.log('Assigning results.invites');
                        results[i].invites = invites;
                        index++;
                        executeStep();
                    });
                }
            }

            executeStep();
        }
    });
}

function getInvites(id, cb) {
    var InvitesTable = tables.getTable("Invites").where({
        "PlanID": id
    }).select("UserID", "Attending");
    InvitesTable.read({
        success: function (results) {
            if (cb) cb(results);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you might do something like this

```
function read(query, user, request) {

    request.execute({
        success: function (results) {
            for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) {
                getInvites(results.id, function (invites) {
                    console.log("Assigning results.invites"); //runs second
                    results.invites = invites;

                    if (i === len-1) request.respond();
                });
            }
            console.log("Request Responding"); //runs first
        }
    });

}

function getInvites(id, cb) {
    var InvitesTable = tables.getTable("Invites").where({
        "PlanID": id
    }).select("UserID", "Attending");
    InvitesTable.read({
        success: function (results) {
            if (cb) cb(results);
        }
    });
}
```

It basically means that `request.respond()` will be called at your successful callback of the last iteration.

Comment: doesn't work :( for loop completes before getInvites call is finished.  So request.respond() still runs first

Comment: Since all the operations from `getInvites` are asynchronous, it is not guaranteed that the last call will be the last to be executed. Your code has a race condition which will likely cause the response to be sent before all the callbacks have been executed.